# Unity real-time multiplayer with node.js (cross-platform with IOS & Android)

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm having hard time to find an answer regarding to develop real-time multiplayer with node.js. Currently i have a small team and wanted to build a realtime multiplayer boardgame(turn base) which will be cross-platform between ios and android. Since we are out of budget to subscribe Photon or Smartfox as the multiplayer server, we suggest to setup our own node.js server. But since we are so new to the real-time multiplayer game development, we are still struggle with the decision whether node.js is the right server for our realtime multiplayer board game.

We are aware that some of the developers mentioned that the speed of node.js is slower since it is using TCP instead of UDP, but we do read some post/tutorial that using node.js as the multiplayer server.

I wanted to know if anyone here use node.js as the server when develop real-time multiplayer game?

Comment: yes. I recommend node.js. and since it's a turn based game TCP is a better option because of its reliability.

Answer (score 1):

Node can do TCP or UDP and can be a great choice as a real time server, however there are some pros and cons (as always):

Pros:

1. Node is easy to develop for due to strong community and plethora of modules and examples
2. By default, your server will be async and will be able to handle a lot of concurrent connections without you really having to do anything

Cons:

1. By default node will run in just one logical thread for all connections, so if you do any compute in response to a message, you are blocking all other responses from your server. So node is best suited to low compute but high I/O servers
2. If your realtime server creates and destroys a lot of objects then you can trigger the garbage collector which will effectively pause your server. This usually completes quickly and when it finishes all received requests will be serviced, but it does mean you get the ocasional spike in latency

So, if your server is low compute, and can handle the *occasional* minor latency spike, node js is a fine choice.

I would suggest designing the server so you can run multiple instances at once, as if you do hit processing bottlenecks you can simply scale horizontally by adding more server instances.

If continuous low latency is a requirement, you could also investigate golang, although it is harder to write for.